# Iterate through a avl tree

Tags: java, tree, loops

I currently write on an `AVL-tree` and write an iterator-method, to iterate through the whole tree in preorder. And I get a `NullPointer` if I process the line 'stack.empty()' and don't have a clue why. And 4 eyes do see it better than two ;). Thank you in beforehand for help in advance.

Code:

```
@Override
public Iterator<E> iterator() {

    return new Iterator<E>(){
        Node start;
        Node current;
        //          int counter;
        Stack<Node> stack;
        //          int border = count(root);

        public void iterator() {

            stack = new Stack<Node>();
            current = start;
            stack.add(root);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            if(stack.empty()) return false;
            else return true;
        }

        @Override
        public E next() {
            if(!hasNext()){
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            }
            Node n = stack.pop();
            if(n.left.value != null) stack.push(n.left);
            if(n.right.value != null) stack.push(n.right);

            return  n.value;            
        }

    };
}
```

Comment: ```Node start``` is not initialized.  Method ```iterator()``` is not called.  It is not a constructor.  You should use instance initializer ```{}```.

Comment: I don't need 'Node start', and if I initialize it, nothing changes. Can you please send me an example code of how I can call the 'iterator()'. Thanks in beforehand :)

Comment: Just enclose the initialize code by ```{}```.  In other words, remove ```public void iterator()```

Comment: Big thank you! Now it works! :)

Answer (score 2):

You probably mean n.left != null

Comment: Eclipse didn't process that far. It just stopped at 'stack.empty()'. There I get a NullPointer :). But still thanks, maybe that would have been an upcoming problem.